RabbitMQ: When a node is down, CreateModel takes longer than usual
I have a RabbitMQ Cluster. I have an application connected to the cluster and works fine. I am not sure if this behaviour is normal but  don't think so: When a node is down, publishing a message takes longer than usual (I am talking between 5 and 10 seconds).
I have the following code to connect to create a channel. Keep in mind this is a singleton for the whole application:
public class RabbitMQConnection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    private readonly object _lock;
    private readonly IList<AmqpTcpEndpoint> _endpoints;
    private bool _shouldClose = false;

    private IConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public RabbitMQConnection(IEnumerable<string> hostList, string username, string password)
    {
        _endpoints = hostList.Select(s =>
        {
            var split = s.Split(':');
            var hostname = split[0];
            int port = -1;
            if (split.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(split[1], out int parsedPort))
                port = parsedPort;
            return new AmqpTcpEndpoint(hostname, port);
        }).ToList();
        _connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            UserName = username,
            Password = password,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
            NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };

        _lock = new object();
    }

    ~RabbitMQConnection() => Dispose();

    private void StartConnection()
    {
        if (_shouldClose)
            return;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (Connection?.IsOpen == true)
                return;

            if (Connection != null)
                Connection.Dispose();

            Connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection(_endpoints);
            Connection.ConnectionShutdown += Connection_ConnectionShutdown;
        }
    }

    private void Connection_ConnectionShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e) => StartConnection();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _shouldClose = true;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (Connection != null)
            {
                if (Connection.IsOpen)
                    Connection.Close();
                Connection.Dispose();
                Connection = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public IModel CreateChannel()
    {
        StartConnection();
        return this.Connection.CreateModel();
    }
}

My issue, as stated, if one of the nodes is down, the line this.Connection.CreateModel() takes about 5 seconds to return. What am I missing here?
